# Sonar sensors sends back random data and shuts down randomly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, sonar-runner

I am working on Sonar sensor which echos the signal and receives back. Also created an algo which calculates the distanc based on the reading. But I am facing some weird problem, sometimes the sensor send random data which is not at all relevant like the actual distance from the object the signal hit is ranging from 5cm - 160cm but sensors sends like 2000+cm. It is very hard to figure out why and also it shuts down itself.

My question is

1. Why the sensors send faulty data sometimes ?
2. How to detect in program that sensor is shut down or alive ?

I am using Sonar sensor on Raspberry pi and using this code

```
# set Trigger to HIGH
GPIO.output(TRIGGER, True)
#print "GPIO", GPIO

# set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIGGER, False)

StartTime = time.time()
StopTime = time.time()

# save StartTime
try:
now = time.time()
    # save the time it takes just before ECHO hears the TRIGGER pulse (0 means nothing received)
    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()
    #print "StartTime ", StartTime
    #print "now: ", now
    if StartTime-now > 1:
        return -1
    #print("StartTime: " , StartTime)       #Printing this causes incorrect measurements.

    # save time of arrival
    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()
    #print("StopTime: ", StopTime)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    return -1

# time difference between start and arrival
TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime

# multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)
# and divide by 2, because there and back
distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2
```

I am using this code to calculate the distance

Comment: Ok, what sensor is it?

Comment: Hi Mark! It's the Ultrasonic Module HC-SR04 Distance Sensor.